# No triggers under the tables node in SSMS but the 'sys.triggers' table still returns results. How is this possible?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, ssms

I recently was working on a production issue at my organization and when I developed a solution, it went well on the Dev environment but when I deployed it to higher environments, I noticed that some database triggers were blocking the fix. When I checked the tables in SSMS, the Triggers folder under each of the tables is empty.

So, I ran the below query and to my surprise some triggers were returned:

`SELECT * FROM SYS.TRIGGERS`

The triggers that were present in the results were pointing to the same tables I was checking. I had admin privileges on the database. So, it can't be a permission issue that I couldn't view the existing triggers under the table node.

My question is: How is it possible that triggers are not visible under the tables but are still existing in the database?

Comment: In my unfortunate experience, the most common are a) The triggers were added after the object explorer retrieved and cached information about those tables (i.e. you should have refreshed it) or b) you were looking at the wrong server/database/tables.

Comment: Were they database triggers (DDL), or were they table triggers (DML)? [`sys.triggers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-triggers-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) returns information about both types.